# how to manage oracle db (XE) service under windows

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle11g

It happened the 2nd time that after a windows update the oracle db services disappeared from services dialog in windows. The last time i just reinstalled oracle db (version 11.2.).
If i google about it i always findthat i should start "DBCA":

> Programs, Oracle - home_name, Configuration and Migration Tools, and
>   then Database Configuration Assistant

But i can't find neither the link in start menu nor a dbca.exe nor any hint where i can download it.

So how to reinstall the oracle db services?

Comment: check this http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_check_verify_windows_services.htm

Comment: did not help. in my case the services aren't installed at all. And installing/starting "OrcaleServiceXE" does not help without "OrcacleXETNSListener". Reinstalling Oracle always helps but i don't want to reinstall after every (major) windows update.